# LAMP/ webdav: my apache error.logs show "su: must be run from a terminal" - but that wasnt me

Tags: lamp, webdav, vulnerability, mod-webdav

within the apache error.log I have the mssg:
"su: must be run from a terminal"
Usually, there are error IDs, the monitored IP and source of the error (php-page)  - all this is missing here.

If I check the apache access.log during the given time-window (the error-mssg before and that one after the entry "su: must be run from a terminal"), there is a hacking-approach: 
PROPFIND /webdav/ HTTP/1.1" 403 0 "-" "WEBDAV Client"
(the IP is already listed in the abuse IP database.list:  https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/192.99.144.140)

Now I wonder, if the "**su: must be run from a terminal**" is normal behaviour if the PROPFIND was rejected properly - or, **if this a clear sign that there is a critical vulnerability**. (I have never added/ activated/ used the webdav module for this server.)

I'd be happy if someone could explain/give further information, where/how this plain mssg "su: must be run from a terminal" is coming from/was generated by.